# IIS 6 Compress static files when using Wildcard application mapping

Tags: .net, asp.net, episerver

I'm using IIS 6 with EPiserver CMS which requires all requests to go through aspnet_isapi.dll.

I want to gzip all my static files (js, css mainly). Trying to setup compression in IIS didn't work.

Is there a setting in EPiServer that will allow me to achieve this? 
Can .net framework compress files automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to configure the html extension in the IIS metabase **as a dynamically compressed extension**. You are probably  treating it as a static page. If the .js and .css extensions are mapped to aspnet_isapi they are considered as dynamic pages.

The setting in [metabase.xml](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/a0ea8e51-fb2a-4e80-9d5a-7fe3ae246570.mspx) should look like this:

```
HcScriptFileExtensions="asp
dll 
exe 
js
css"
```

Don't forget to remove the extensions from `HcFileExtensions` (for static files) if you inserted them there before.

*Hope this helps.*

Answer (score 1):

What if you wanted to gzip all files (for use in a web service with extensionless URLs)?