# IIS 6 js & css compression not working for Firefox 14.0.1

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-3, compression, iis-6

I wanted to make this quick but I'm unable to get it working despite all my efforts or probably I'm missing something or overlooking!

I'e an ASP.Net based MVC3 web app setup on IIS6. I've setup the simple IIS compression for both static & dynamic content compression from inetmgr (IIS manager). And also edited the Metabase.xml file for IIS to fine-tune the HcFileExtensions in IIsCompressionScheme (for both Gzip & deflate). Also followed many linked like [this one](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/08/http-compression-and-iis-6-0.html) and tried a lot.

But I'm unable to see it in my Firefox 14.0.1 using Firebug and YSlow - it says the js files and css content is NOT compressed. I've a lot of jQuery and css. And yes, I've already restarted my IIS many times, cleared browser cache, ctrl  + F5, etc... Also tried with [ZipEnabled](http://www.port80software.com/download/index_detail.asp).

*One more thing - does CDN reference ensure compression? I mean its not coming from my IIS so I believe it might not.*

Thanks.

**SO ref reviewed -** 
[IIS 6 Compress static files when using Wildcard application mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287703/iis-6-compress-static-files-when-using-wildcard-application-mapping)
[Gzip compression with MVC3 issue on IIS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752898/gzip-compression-with-mvc3-issue-on-iis-6)

Comment: Have you looked at the HTTP transaction with the Firefox add-on "Tamper Data"?

Comment: Well, I thought Firebug would show me the zip encoding

Comment: Are you seeing compression when using different browsers? I have some notes about enabling compression on IIS6 as it's not as straightforward as you might imagine...

Comment: I've to see the compression in IE & FF because those are the two we've to support foremost. Anyway, pls provide me what you got because I've tried many things and it looks like IIS7 does it better then IIS6 (if at all it does)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've to conclude that the IIS6 compression for static & dynamic content **does not seem to work** for Firefox 14.0.1 where as I got gzipped content with Firefox 18+ even in opera (haven't tested for chrome yet)

I also derive that IIS7 provides a decent way to manage the compression settings compared to IIS6.